# Building OpenSSL FIPS for arm64

Tags: ios, openssl, arm64, fips

I've found references for building non-FIPS openssl for arm64 but I need to build the FIPS version.

Projects like https://github.com/GotoHack/iOS-openSSL-FIPS build armv7 versions but I can't seem to extend them to arm64. Has anyone successfully done this?

I'm using os-x to compile, the target is IOS

Answer (score 2):

> I've found references for building non-FIPS openssl for arm64 but I need to build the FIPS version.

You can't at the moment. The platform (iOS, ARM64, A7/A8 chips) has not been validated. See section 3.2 *Known Supported Platforms* in [OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0 User Guide](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf).

If you want a validated arn64 build, then you will have to engage the [OpenSSL Foundation for a private label validation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html).