# OpenSSL FIPS capable library for iOS arm64 architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, fips

I am successfully generating OpenSSL FIPS capable library for iOS armv7 architecture by referring Appendix E 
from https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf

However for arm64 architecture with grater than iOS8 I am trying to build FIPS capable library by tweaking setenv-ios-11.sh setenv-darwin-i386.sh files and compiler but it is throwing below error.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/
llvm-gcc: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

How do I build the OpenSSL FIPS capable library for iOS arm64 architecture?

Comment: Also see [Building OpenSSL FIPS for arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27911776/608639) and [Openssl FIPS version for iPhone armv7, armv7s & arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38662794/608639).

Comment: Hi @jww ,Thanks for your response, I already seen those before, but those were answered before 1 or 2 years.. so wanted to check whether it is possible now or not. and https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.16.pdf stating that iOS 8.1 64­bit on Apple A7 (ARMv8) (without/with optimizations) has been added.What actually means that, can we build OpenSSL with FIPS for 64 bit architecture on any iOS version according that statement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to GCC path. So you need to link gcc to your path by below command.

Details: [llvm-gcc-4.2: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293298/llvm-gcc-4-2-error)

**Fix the issue on iOS devices:**

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc gcc-4.2
```